# Indexed but blocked by robots.txt on my english cart

Tags: prestashop, sitemap, robots.txt, google-search-console, indexed

i have a small issue checking on google search console. It display only 1 error
`Indexed, though blocked by robots.txt`
but is on my website in the english version (the italian version is ok). How can i fix it?
This is the link that is blocked https://www.cebsas.it/en/cart

Many thanks
Nicola

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the "Disallow: /*controller=cart" line and this is true.

You have to remove Cart page from indexed pages

Comment: I checked on my website's backoffice where i can create the sitemap, but is already removed the cart page from indexed pages

Comment: This link may have been somewhere  on your site or other sites, and Google has indexed it. np